# Getting an exception when query oracle with Dbutils

Tags: java, oracle, apache-commons-dbutils

Codes:

```
QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
connection = JdbcUtils.getConnection();
String sql = "SELECT id,name,address,phone FROM customer WHERE name LIKE ?";
List<Customer> list = queryRunner.query(connection,sql,new BeanListHandler<Customer>(Customer.class), "%j%");
for(Customer c: list){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

When I query with my own DAO code,it's OK.But with queryRunner,following exception appears：

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "NAMEIKE": invalid identifier
Query: SELECT id,name,address,phone FROM customer WHERE name LIKE ? Parameters: [%j%]
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:392)
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:351)
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:212)
at com.lteagle.mvcapp.test.Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

I don't know where the invalid identifier "NAMEIKE" come from.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ..What is J, the parameter you are passing to query method of query runner

```
QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
connection = JdbcUtils.getConnection();
String sql = "SELECT id,name,address,phone FROM customer WHERE name LIKE ?";
List<Customer> list = queryRunner.query(connection,sql,new BeanListHandler<Customer>(Customer.class), "%"+j+"%");
for(Customer c: list){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: I want to fuzzy query,'j' is just a character in 'name'.